# Printing multiple documents with c#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I would like to print silent multiple files (txt, pdf, htm, ...) using C # .Net. I tried various ways, I used ShellExecute, Process, PrintDocument, all without success. There is an application "http://www.print-conductor.com/download/" which does exactly what I need, does anyone have any idea how it works? Example, it prints pdf files without opening the adobe reader, not even in task manager adobe appears, the only requirement is to have his application associated with the file. Grateful for any help.

With the ShellExecute method below I can send the print, but in case of pdf Adobe Reader is open, the quiet was he not open, and the file to be sent directly to the print queue.

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShellExecute")]
    private static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(IntPtr hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, string lpParameters,
                                              string lpDirectory, ShowCommands nShowCmd);

    public bool Print(string fullPath)
    {
        var result = false;
        try
        {
            var resultPrint = ShellExecute(IntPtr.Zero, "Print", fullPath, "", "", ShowCommands.SwShowminimized).ToInt32();
            if (resultPrint > 32) result = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I apologize for the way that put the first part of the question, I am upset for failing to deliver the project I'm already 3 weeks and nothing, forgive me.

Another unsuccessful attempt, the file appears in the print queue, but it prints blank:

```
public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }
    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var defaultPrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
        RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(defaultPrintQueue.FullName, @"C:\Temp\Teste.pdf");

    }
}
```

With the option below Adobe Reader also opens and remains open:

```
public void Print(string fullPath, string printerName)
    {
        Process process = new Process
                              {
                                  StartInfo =
                                      {
                                          FileName = fullPath,
                                          UseShellExecute = true,
                                          Verb = "printto",
                                          Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\""
                                      }
                              };

        process.Start();
    }
```

- Visual Studio 2013, C#, Windows 8.1

Comment: You say you tried various ways, but you didn't explain how they didn't work. How are we supposed to know what you did wrong? And what does "print silent" mean?

Comment: Questions that are merely requirements with no effort shown are not usually well received on Stack Overflow. Instead, show (in code) what has been attempted to far to solve the problem and what issues are currently being encountered along with a specific, answerable, objective question.

Comment: yes, show your code then only we can understand what logic you used and where it failed

Comment: Again I apologize for the way I put the question, I'm a little disappointed not to get a shape that suits me, I edited the question and put the code I used. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Print Conductor's 'How it Works' link it says:

"Print Conductor’s special ability is to automatically dispatch documents to other programs for printing.

....

Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat is required to print PDF files."

So in fact it *does* open Acrobat (or at least, an application associated with PDF files) in order to print them. I'm afraid that to print arbitrary document types you need an application which understands how to read the document, and how to render it.

Some document types are understood by the Operating System (eg Windows and XPS files) and can be printed without any additional software, but in the general case there is no such solution.

Comment: Ken thanks for the reply, I have this software installed on my machine, I performed several tests. I noticed he asks the associated application, but as I mentioned, he printed the pdf file without opening Adobe Reader, the document goes to queue direct printing.

Comment: To be honest, if the software developer says it needs Acrobat to print, I'm inclined to believe them....

Comment: I agree with you and with them, but have some idea of how they can send that impression without opening Adobe Reader?

Comment: Possibly it is using some other application, or some technique by which it simply doesn't show up in your task manager. Its hardly infallible.